# How to browse through box.com folders to select a file and download the selected file

Tags: vba, excel, cloud, box-api

I need a excel macro (vba) to select a file from box.com by iterating though existing folders and at the same time I need to upload the file from my machine to box.com folder using excel macro. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

-Edit

I am using the below code for getting authentication token. But I am getting an error message at the place of .send(url). Error message is "The server name or address could not be resolved".

```
Function getAuthToken()

    Dim WinHttpReq As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim api_key As String

    api_key = "{api_key}"

    Set WinHttpReq = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

   strUrl = "https://www.box.net/api/1.0/rest?action=get_ticket&api_key=" & api_key

  WinHttpReq.Open Method:="GET", url:=strUrl, async:=False
  WinHttpReq.Send
  getTicket = WinHttpReq.responseText
  Debug.Print getTicket

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Not being a vba expert, I suspect that you'll get more answers if you tag your question with a vba tag.   However, some quick scanning around shows that vba can call REST apis by doing something like this:

```
Dim MyURL as String
MyURL = "http://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0.xml"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

With objHTTP
    .Open "GET", MyURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key=<your api key>&auth_token=<your auth token>
    .send (MyURL)
End With
```

I'll defer to a real VBA expert, but something roughly along these lines should work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tagged this question under vba. I will try this and let you know the findings. Anyway great thanks for valuable information.

Comment: Can you please post the code to get the auth token by passing api-key using excel - vba?

Comment: Are you trying to get an auth-token for a user?   I assume you've already gotten an API key and read through the user-flow for auth http://developers.box.com/get-started/#authenticating

Comment: But my code is running into errors at .Send (url). The error message is "The server name or address could not be resolved". If you want see the code. I will post.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is frustrating. I tried code like Peter's using both WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 and MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP and with both I just get a zero-length string back. No error message or anything.

I installed cURL and tested the URL.  It works fine there.  The script below also works fine with a generic JSON web service, like jsonplaceholder.typicode.com.

All this makes me think that Box.com is receiving the message, detecting it is coming from a non-approved source, and returning nothing . . . probably for security reasons.

```
Option Explicit
Const URL As String = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 -H ""Authorization: Bearer MyToken"""
'Const URL As String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
Sub Test()

    Dim winHTTP As Object
'    Set winHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Set winHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    winHTTP.Open "GET", URL
    winHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    winHTTP.send
    Debug.Print winHTTP.ResponseText

    If Len(winHTTP.ResponseText) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "blank string returned"
    Else
        Dim objResponse As Object
        Set objResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(winHTTP.ResponseText) 'Converter from Tim Hall - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
    End If



 End Sub
```